# Running Xcode 4 locally, executing code externally?

Tags: xcode, cuda

We have a CUDA server at work that is running Linux.

I am running Xcode on my Mac which does not have a CUDA device. I wondered if it was possible to use Xcode 4 as an IDE to develop the code, but executing/building and debugging the code on the external CUDA server?

In other words, I want to store the files etc, on the CUDA server (I have SSH access), but manage the project/files from my Mac. When I press the build button in Xcode, I want everything to be build on the CUDA server.

Is this possible or do I have to use ssh and vim to develop my code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xcode (not a Mac user), but you don't need to use vim -- develop in Xcode and use git or rsync to transfer the whole project. Or you can instal some IDE onto the CUDA server and run it on your machine via forwarded X.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible but I know you can configure some version control system from inside Xcode to keep the server updated with your latest code. You can also build the code in Xcode without having a cuda capable card. You would only have to use ssh and a makefile to build and test on the external server.

Answer (score 1):

How about mounting the Linux server over SFTP through the Finder, and then using Xcode to start a project directly on the server?  It might be tricky to tell Xcode where to find the nvcc compiler and other necessary stuff on the Linux server, but I would try that first.